# convert .net format string to java format string

Tags: c#, java, string-formatting

I am looking at the format specifiers of C# and the patterns for formatting numeric strings in Java.

I am wondering if anyone has any pointers as to translating from one form to another?

Comment: Could you provide an example that you need translated?

Answer (score 1):

this gives you an overview of the [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) .net format strings. You can find the Java format string syntax [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).